# input with delimiters in python

Tags: python, input, stdin

I have a problem with the following specification:

**Input:**

First line contains an integer  N , the number of element in the given sequnce.
Then follows N integers A1, A2.... An,  Ai is ith element of the given sequence. These numbers may be either space separated or newline separated.

How can I handle an input like that?
I tried the following,but it only works for space separated elements.When used with newline separated elements the grader throws "time exceeded"

```
import sys
counter=0
A=[]
for line in sys.stdin:
    if counter!=0:
        A+=[int(Ai) for Ai in line.split()]
    else:
        N=int(line)
        counter+=1
```

Comment: `line.split()` also works on delimiters like `,` and many more.

Comment: yes but on every line I have either only spaces or only a number.There are no other delimiters

Comment: As far as I can tell, your code works fine (so long as the first line contains only 1 number) and so long as the data is put into `sys.stdin` (and `sys.stdin` is properly terminated) ... Of course, you'll grab a lot more than just N elements ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you're reading from a file (`sys.stdin` is also a file):

```
f = open('path/to/file')
N = int(f.readline().strip())
A = []
while len(A) < N:
    A.extend(int(i) for i in f.readline().strip().split())
```

Hope this helps

Comment: You don't need to open `sys.stdin`. It's already an open file

Comment: so I write: 
N = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
A = []
while len(A) < N:
    A.extend(int(i) for i in sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())